# Regular Expression Notepad++ HTML child not contains

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file that has many `<request>` elements and I'd like to find all `<request>` tags that do not contain `<boop>`.

`<request>` can have many tags before and after `<boop>` (like `<beep>` and `<bop>` in the example below).

```
<request>
   <beep>
   </beep>
   <boop>
   </boop>
   <bop>
   </bop>
</request>
```

I've tried `<request>.*?<\/request>` which matches each `<request>`

Expanding on that with a negitive lookahead I get:

`<request>.*?(?!<boop>).*?<\/request>`

but that dosen't seem to work.

I have *regular expression* and *matches newline* selected with my search.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may try `(?s)<request>(?:(?!<(?:request|boop)>).)*?</request>`. Or [`<request>[^<]*(?:<(?!(?:request|boop)>)[^<]*)*</request>`](https://regex101.com/r/0jIMlj/2).

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! It works great. I have spent hours on this. Please post an answer so I can upvote. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++, you may use the following regexps *granted your `<request>` tags cannot be nested*:

```
(?s)<request>(?:(?!<(?:request|boop)>).)*?</request>
```

Or

```
<request>[^<]*(?:<(?!(?:request|boop)>)[^<]*)*</request>
```

See an [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/0jIMlj/2).

Note you do not need to worry about the *`.` matches newline* option with these patterns. The second one is the same as the first one, it is its unrolled variant (which should work considerably faster since it does not have to test each char on its way to the `</request>` end delimiter, it matches whole chunks of text from `<` to `<`).

**Details**

- `(?s)` - an inline DOTALL modifier (= *`.` matches newline* ON)
- `<request>` - start delimiter
- `(?:(?!<(?:request|boop)>).)*?` - any char (`.`), 0+ repetitions (`*`), as few as possible (`?`, actually, `*?` quantifier) that is not starting a `<request>` or `<boop>` character sequence
- `</request>` - end delimiter.